# Mapping 3 argument function to a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

The map function works fine on really easy functions that take no arguments like *7 to every element in a list of Ints.

But say I made a custom function that takes a Char, String and Int and then returns a Char and I wanted to apply this function to a list of Chars i.e. a String to get a String back after applying the other function to each Char? When I try this all I get is error messages?

Comment: You mean something like this: `map (\x -> f x "string" 10) "another string"` ?

Comment: What is the expected result of applying your function to a single `Char`?

Comment: map doesn't work on functions that take *no* arguments, but on functions that take *one* argument. The type of map is: `map::(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. `(a -> b)` is a function that takes a value of type `a` to return another of type `b`.

Comment: @S.R.I I don't care if it's 0 or 1 argument, I know what it does! All I want to know is how I can map a function that takes many arguments to a list.

Comment: @Eddie, can you refine your question, then? In particular, answer [n.m](http://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m)'s question - or IOW, can you take partial function application?

Comment: So tell us what it does.

Comment: The first function takes a Char, a mixed up alphabet and an Int that shifts that alphabet (often zero) and returns the new Int. The other function should be able to do this with a String.

Comment: So what's wrong with the proposed answer then?

Comment: When I try it with a lambda it compiles fine but when I try to use the function I get an error message say "lexical error at character"?

Comment: Works here. You probably mistyped it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example input and output...and also the error messages you are getting with the souce code you are using

Answer (score 1):

Put your `Char` argument to the last position:

```
foo :: String -> Int -> Char -> Char
foo str num c = c

bar = map (foo str num)
```

But we really need some more information from your side to help you better. Can you add the code you tried to write to your question?